# eel cannot find Google Chrome

Tags: python, replit, oserror, eel

```
import eel

eel.init('web')

eel.expose
def Something():
  return "hhaa tf"

eel.start("index.html")
```

I am trying to use eel to display a thing and it is giving me the **OSError** that it cannot find Google Chrome or Chromium. I am running this in **Replit** which I think is the problem and I need a solution thanks.

Answer (score -2):

```py
eel.start("index.html", mode="browser")
```

Answer (score -3):

try this:
eel.start("index.html", mode="browser")